# How do i resolve Error: The requested address was not found on this server - CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm using CakePHP 2.X in my project and stuck at one point.

First of all let you know that i implemented search functionality using form's **POST** Method, But for this i found error in pagination. Filter will not sustain for next page. So i changed form method to **GET**. now its working OK **( Not exactly what i required, All requested data displaying in URL )**, but now i'm at the point where its create another issue.

**I got below error when i trying to search anything ( Existing data in DB ), and go to next page using pagination, now i changed search keyword with not matched in DB ( Data Not Exist in DB ).**

> Error: The requested address was not found on this server

Which was not there at the time of POST method.

I have tried with all the option in **debug mode** (`Configure::write('debug', 2)`). but not getting any help from it.

Can anyone help me out from this? It will be really appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Did you enable debug mode (> 0)? That will tell you more. Also check the error logs.

Comment: Yes, i did that.no help!

Comment: What is the exact error message you get then? Including the stacktrace? You need to also show us some code.

Comment: Yes, including **Stack Trace**

Comment: @Chandresh indeed do **include the stack trace in the quesetion**. If you're looking at a white page with only that text the problem that isn't generated by CakePHP - it's your webserver indicating the lack of mod rewrite and a wrong url.

Comment: Check either the stack trace CakePHP generates when the debug mode is set to 2 (and post it in your question so we call help more); or check your **/app/tmp/logs/error.log** file.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is simple.

```
lib/Cake/Controller/PaginatorComponent.php
if ($requestedPage > $page) { 
        throw new NotFoundException();
}
```

So just catch the error in your controller.

```
public function index() {
    try {
        $this->Paginator->paginate();
    } catch (NotFoundException $e) {
        //Do something here like redirecting to first or last page.
        //$this->request->params['paging'] will give you required info.
    }
}
```

This is why: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#out-of-range-page-requests