# CakePHP - Notice (8): Undefined variable: controller [APP/View/Errors/missing_controller.ctp, line 34]

Tags: php, cakephp, controller, cakephp-2.0

I'm working on one of the CakePHP Site, URL which i would like to use is given below,

```
www.myhost.com/requestuser
```

Actually above URL working fine in my local server, but its creating error when i upload and tried to run on live server

```
www.myhost.com/requestuser
```

**Error : Notice (8): Undefined variable: controller [APP/View/Errors/missing_controller.ctp, line 34]**

Controller name / Model Name : RequestUserController/RequestUser

but Its working fine if i use below URL on live sever,

```
www.myhost.com/RequestUser
```

Can anybody please help me out why its displaying error with previous URL (www.myhost.com/requestuser)

Comment: Sounds to me like you're using a server with case-sensitivity issues. Linux servers react differently than Windows servers do. On Linux, `Var` is not the same as `var`. You could use a `Redirect` Apache directive to redirect if you want to go that route.

Comment: Yes, i'm using Linux server for live, but all other links works perfectly with same structure, problem occurs with this new module only!

Comment: Hm... most bizarre. Are all the other modules with the same structure also on the Linux server and working well?

Comment: Yes, Thats what confusing me!

Comment: Is there anything related to it that could be inside an `.htaccess` file? Also double check your controller files for letter-case.

Comment: This happens when your server has no mode rewrite enabled. You need to post your htaccess script here for people to help you. And also check with the server PHP infor if mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: I noticed from another one of your questions and the [`answer given`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22132018/) that if you're using what the person answered with `lib/Cake/Controller/PaginatorComponent.php` and that the file on your (Linux) server is called `paginatorcomponent.php` all in lowercase letters, then that would explain it. @Chandresh --- This goes for folder names also. Again, Linux servers are case-sensitive.

Comment: are you following cake naming conventions? Your controller name should be `RequestUsersController` and not `RequestUserController`. And your url should be `www.myhost.com/request_users`